# shouldComponentUpdate usecase scenario

Tags: reactjs

[image]

> The last interesting case is C8. React had to render this component,
>   but since the React elements it returned were equal to the previously
>   rendered ones, it didn’t have to update the DOM.

So this is taken from the official react docs.

For C8, SCU returns true and also Virtual DOMs (previous and next) are equal. How is this possible ?

The only scenario I can think of is when you are passing props to C8 but not using them in the render method of C8.

Can someone elaborate this with an appropriate example ?

Answer (score 1):

Every time a React component receives new state or props, it attempts to re-render.  But as you stated, sometimes certain props or state values do not affect the output that is rendered.

A simple example would be a component that contains a property such as a counter for a button but never actually displays the output of that counter.  Because the counter is stored as a state value, the component will attempt to re-render every time it is updated but the dom will not actually need to update because the element is the same.

If your component will always produce the same output given the same input props use a [Pure Component](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent) which will perform a shallow comparison and will only re-render when state or props will produce an output.